# Tl494 with gate driver IC output voltage problem

Tags: mosfet, power-electronics, inverter, mosfet-driver, tl494

Recently I've got my hands on some ETD42 ferrite cores and decided to make a 300W pure sine wave inverter.  I chose the TL494 SMPS IC for driving the booster circuit (12 to 340V) and using the EG8010 module with an H-bridge to create the sine wave.  So for the topology, I chose push-pull.  I don't want to use the TL494 to drive FETs so I used the TC4420 gate driver IC to drive them.
[image: TL494 to TC4420 connection]

[image]
Sorry about the bad drawing

The emitter is tied to ground via 1k resistor to form an emitter follower circuit.  The signal is then fed to the gate driver IC.  The supply voltage for the TL494 is 9V, and for TC4420, 12V.  The frequency is 40kHz at 45% duty cycle for testing purposes.

So now the question is: the circuit works as it's supposed to, but the problem is, when checking the gate voltage of the MOSFET, the voltage is quite low (around 5V), which is not enough to turn the MOSFET fully on and off.  Is there any way that the gate voltage can be increased to at least 10V?

If you need more info, I will reply soon as possible.  Thank you.

Comment: How are you measuring the voltage, and with what?

Comment: I measure the voltage with my multimeter it shows around 5.56v.the signal voltage from the tl494 is around 3.4v

Comment: but if the gate drive pulse width is 50%, you will measure approximately half of the peak voltage as the meter will average the value. Your schematic is nowhere near complete to draw any useful conclusions from.

Comment: I can draw the schematic if needed.the circuit is normal the tl494 gives out a constant frequency and duty cycle, then that signal is fed to the driver ic.so is it normal to read half the supply voltage at gate because of 50% duty? So is there 10v peak to peak voltage on gate ?

Comment: Okey i will update the post soon as possible with a schematic

Comment: Yeah, that looks normal. You need an oscilloscope to measure the waveforms and see what high/low voltage, pulse width, etc. are.

Comment: Ouh alright then thank you very much @TimWilliams.